# For setup vue storefront : when Installing the vue-storefront-api locally, it throws error for vue storefront page on Ubuntu

Tags: magento2, pwa, ubuntu, vue

After installation of vue storefront, when I open page for storefront, display page like something went wrong. And also display console error

> The connection to http://localhost:3000/__webpack_hmr was interrupted
>   while the page was loading

And display page as shown in image.

[image]

Comment: Did you run this command **npm run migrate** inside **vue-storefront-api** directory ? I think CMS pages data is not migrated there.

Comment: @KishanSavaliya Yes i was run command, but it throws error : https://nimb.ws/VRXals. Can you please check.

Comment: Please setup **Redis, ElasticSearch and Docker** first and then try to run migrate command.

Comment: @KishanSavaliya yes, now storefront page is display but Product is not displaying while click the category, Notification(The product, category or CMS page is not available in Offline mode. Redirecting to Home.) is displayed and product is directly accessible via product link. please check - http://prnt.sc/qbd7sg

Comment: YOU have to merge that data using npm run migrate command you need to run that command inside vue-storefront-api directory

Comment: @KishanSavaliya i run command npm run migrate but still not working

Comment: You got any errors there when you ran that command ?

Comment: no, command ran proper with complete status - https://nimb.ws/ztGKrj

Comment: Please run **npm run dev** inside vue-storefront and vue-storefront-api both directory and check.

Comment: @KishanSavaliya After shutdown system, vue store frontend can't access (localhost:3000) nimb.ws/0PcuXn . Any idea regarding this ?

Comment: You have to run **npm run dev** command again in vue-storefront and api directory then it will work again

Comment: @KishanSavaliya I have run npm run dev command, but it's take too long time & Process can't be complete
Should I run any other command ?
Also after adding new theme and related changes on file(main-image.json for change title), but not display any changes. How can I see updated changes in frontend.